# How do I withdraw the rhs from a list of equations?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, evaluation

I have a list of equations that were solved for different values of another parameter and stored in a Table and has the form:

```
{a==0, a==1, a==2, a==3}
```

and so on. I want to withdraw only in rhs and store it in a list:

```
{0, 1, 2, 3}
```

I tried /.ToRules on the whole list as well as on the single elements because I thought, they could be evaluated easier. I expected
`{a->0,a->1,a->2,a->3}` but it's giving me the same error for either one:
"{ToRules} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing"

Comment: Thanks for accepting a good answer, however I think you were too hasty doing that. While *accepting* is one of the [things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4), we recommend that users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. That allows people in all time zones to answer your question and an opportunity for other users to point alternatives, caveats or limitations of the available answers.

Comment: Ok, that makes it 10+ different solutions then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps

```
{a == 0, a == 1, a == 2, a == 3}[[All, 2]]
(*{0, 1, 2, 3}*)
```

or

```
{a == 0, a == 1, a == 2, a == 3} /.Equal->Rule
(*{a -> 0, a -> 1, a -> 2, a -> 3}*)
```

Comment: fyi, you have typo. `Rules` should be `Rule`

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for your hint

Answer (score 5):

Using `MapApply` and `Values`:

```
Rule @@@ lis

(*{a -> 0, a -> 1, a -> 2, a -> 3}*)

Values@(Rule @@@ lis)

(*{0, 1, 2, 3}*)
```

Answer (score 5):

## Using [`ToRules`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRules.html)

You wanted to use [`ToRules`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRules.html). You could have [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) (`/@`) it like this

```
ToRules/@{a == 0, a == 1, a == 2, a == 3}
(* {{a->0},{a->1},{a->2},{a->3}} *)
```

So a complete solution

```
Composition[First, Values, ToRules] /@ {a == 0, a == 1, a == 2, a == 3}
(*{0, 1, 2, 3}*)
```

or

```
First@*Values@*ToRules /@ {a == 0, a == 1, a == 2, a == 3}
(*{0, 1, 2, 3}*)
```

## Using [`MapApply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapApply.html) [`Last`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Last.html)

```
Last @@@ {a == 0, a == 1, a == 2, a == 3}
(*{0, 1, 2, 3}*)
```

This is a hack that relies on the LHS (in this case `a`) been `AtomQ`.

## Using [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html)

```
Cases[
    {a == 0, a == 1, a == 2, a == 3}
    ,  Equal[lhs_,rhs_]:> rhs
]
(*{0, 1, 2, 3}*)
```

## Using [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)

```
{a == 0, a == 1, a == 2, a == 3} /. Equal[lhs_,rhs_]:> rhs
(*{0, 1, 2, 3}*)
```

or in operator mode

```
ReplaceAll[ Equal[lhs_,rhs_]:> rhs] @ {a == 0, a == 1, a == 2, a == 3}
(*{0, 1, 2, 3}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility

```
lis = {a == 0, a == 1, a == 2, a == 3}
Last /@ lis
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In an equation `Last` is the RHS and `First` is the LHS.

If you want to make it Rule, I think Ulrich answer might be the easiest, which is to replace `==` by `Rule`. But you can also do

```
lis = {a == 0, a == 1, a == 2, a == 3}
Rule[First[#], Last[#]] & /@ lis
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

One possible way using **`Values`**:

```
lis = {a == 0, a == 1, a == 2, a == 3};
lis /. Equal -> Rule // Values
```

> {0, 1, 2, 3}

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked about rules, the following will replace each value appropriately

```
MapThread[ReplaceAll, {Table[a, {i, 1, Length@l}], 
  l /. Equal -> Rule}]
```

> `{0,1,2,3}`